# How many sets of variables do I need to assess all pairwise correlations in a planned missing design

Tags: missing-data, combinatorics, survey-sampling, latin-square

I have 54 variables that I need to correlate, but due to constraints I can only put up a maximum of 16 variables at a time for data collection. At the end of the day, I need estimates of the 1,431 pairwise correlations between the 54 variables. How can I figure out the smallest number of 16 variable sets that will allow me to estimate all 1,431 pairwise correlations - as well as the composition of those sets?

To use a small *p* example. If I have 4 variables but can only assess in groups of up to 3, then it seems to me that the smallest number of sets is 3, for example:

```
set1: [1, 2, 3]
set2: [2, 3, 4]
set3: [1, 4, 2]
```

These three sets fill out the 6 pairwise correlations as follows:

```
set1: [1,2], [1,3], [2,3]
set2: [2,3], [2,4], [3,4]
set3: [1,4], [1,2], [4,2]
```

I "double sample" three cells in this design, for example [1,2] is sampled in both set 1 and set 3, but that's fine.

I can't think of an efficient way to design the sets for a situation where the number of variables is high (in this case 54) as is the number of variables I can have in any one set (in this case 16).

any advice much appreciated!

M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is related to a couple topics in combinatorics and graph theory. If we imagine a graph containing the vertices labelled 1 to 54 and edges connecting each pair of vertices (a complete graph on 54 vertices, $K_{54}$), then you're looking for a collection of cliques of 16 vertices such that the collection contains every edge in the complete graph.

Alternatively, an $(n,k,t)$-covering design is a collection of subsets of size $k$ of elements from $(1, 2, ..., n)$, called blocks, such that every possible subset of $t$ different points is in at least one of the blocks. There is a huge amount of research into these designs and related topics, which I don't know well enough to summarize.

In your situation you want a $(54,16,2)$-covering design. This site has an online database of some covering designs and references, https://www.dmgordon.org/cover/ Searching the database we find this design with 16 blocks of size 16.

```
  1  2 10 13 16 18 20 23 27 31 37 43 46 47 51 54
  1  3  5  6  7  9 11 12 16 18 20 24 26 39 48 54
  1  4 14 16 18 20 21 25 29 33 38 40 41 42 44 54
  1  8 16 18 19 20 22 25 28 32 36 45 49 50 52 54
  1  9 10 15 17 19 21 25 30 33 34 35 36 44 45 53
  2  3  4  5 23 24 28 29 36 40 41 42 43 45 50 51
  2  6  7  9 11 12 14 19 21 25 32 33 43 44 49 51
  2  8 15 17 22 26 30 34 35 38 39 43 48 51 52 53
  3  5  8 10 14 21 22 24 25 31 33 37 44 46 47 52
  3  5 13 15 17 19 23 24 27 30 32 34 35 38 49 53
  4  6  7  8  9 11 12 13 22 23 27 29 40 41 42 52
  4  7 12 14 15 16 17 28 29 30 34 35 37 41 50 53
  4 10 19 26 29 31 32 37 39 40 41 42 46 47 48 49
  6  7  9 10 11 12 19 28 31 36 37 38 45 46 47 50
  6 11 15 17 18 20 30 31 34 35 40 42 46 47 53 54
  6 13 14 21 23 25 26 27 28 33 36 39 44 45 48 50
```

Which we can check includes all pairs, as desired.

```r
inc_mat <- matrix(data = 0, nrow = 54, ncol = 54)
inc_mat[upper.tri(inc_mat)] <- 1
verts <- list(
  c(1,  2, 10, 13, 16, 18, 20, 23, 27, 31, 37, 43, 46, 47, 51, 54),
  c(1,  3,  5,  6,  7,  9, 11, 12, 16, 18, 20, 24, 26, 39, 48, 54),
  c(1,  4, 14, 16, 18, 20, 21, 25, 29, 33, 38, 40, 41, 42, 44, 54),
  c(1,  8, 16, 18, 19, 20, 22, 25, 28, 32, 36, 45, 49, 50, 52, 54),
  c(1,  9, 10, 15, 17, 19, 21, 25, 30, 33, 34, 35, 36, 44, 45, 53),
  c(2,  3,  4,  5, 23, 24, 28, 29, 36, 40, 41, 42, 43, 45, 50, 51),
  c(2,  6,  7,  9, 11, 12, 14, 19, 21, 25, 32, 33, 43, 44, 49, 51),
  c(2,  8, 15, 17, 22, 26, 30, 34, 35, 38, 39, 43, 48, 51, 52, 53),
  c(3,  5,  8, 10, 14, 21, 22, 24, 25, 31, 33, 37, 44, 46, 47, 52),
  c(3,  5, 13, 15, 17, 19, 23, 24, 27, 30, 32, 34, 35, 38, 49, 53),
  c(4,  6,  7,  8,  9, 11, 12, 13, 22, 23, 27, 29, 40, 41, 42, 52),
  c(4,  7, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 28, 29, 30, 34, 35, 37, 41, 50, 53),
  c(4, 10, 19, 26, 29, 31, 32, 37, 39, 40, 41, 42, 46, 47, 48, 49),
  c(6,  7,  9, 10, 11, 12, 19, 28, 31, 36, 37, 38, 45, 46, 47, 50),
  c(6, 11, 15, 17, 18, 20, 30, 31, 34, 35, 40, 42, 46, 47, 53, 54),
  c(6, 13, 14, 21, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 33, 36, 39, 44, 45, 48, 50)
)
for(i in 1:length(verts)) {
  inc_mat[verts[[i]],verts[[i]]] <- 0
}
sum(inc_mat)
#> [1] 0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you David this is great!!